# Gson - JsonSerializer in TypeAdapterFactory or generic type in TypeAdapter

Tags: java, javafx, gson

I am trying to write a `TypeAdapterFactory` for the JavaFX Types that I am using (different properties and observables). For the `ObjectProperty` i could write a `JsonSerializer/Deserializer` making use of a cast to `ParamterizedType` and then getting the `ActualTypeArguments`.

This is the code I use to achieve this:

```
public class ObjectPropertySerializer implements JsonSerializer<ObjectProperty>, JsonDeserializer<ObjectProperty> {

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Type objectType = ((ParameterizedType)typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return new SimpleObjectProperty(new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, objectType));
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(ObjectProperty src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Type objectType = ((ParameterizedType)typeOfSrc).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return new GsonBuilder().create().toJsonTree(src.getValue(), objectType);
    }
}
```

However I also need to use a `TypeAdapterFactory` because of nested classes/object and direct serialisation, that do not work when registering the serialisers directly to a `GsonBuilder` using `.registerTypeAdapter()`.

This is the code of my factory so far (the other properties already work):

```
public class JFXGsonAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if ( BooleanProperty.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType()) ) {
            return (TypeAdapter<T>) new BooleanPropertyAdapter();
        }
        else if ( DoubleProperty.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType()) ) {
            return (TypeAdapter<T>) new DoublePropertyAdapter();
        }
        else if (IntegerProperty.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType()) ) {
            return (TypeAdapter<T>) new IntegerPropertyAdapter();
        }
        else if (ObjectProperty.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType()) ) {
            return (TypeAdapter<T>) new ObjectPropertyAdapter(gson);
        }
        else if ( StringProperty.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType()) ) {
            return (TypeAdapter<T>) new StringPropertyAdapter();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't return an implementation of the serializer/deserializer interfaces here, but need to use an adapter class that extends `TypeAdapter`.

Here is my `TypeAdapter` implementation for `ObjectProperty`:

```
public class ObjectPropertyAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<ObjectProperty> {

    private Gson gson;
    TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter;

    public ObjectPropertyAdapter( Gson gson ) {
        this.gson = gson;
        elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, ObjectProperty value) throws IOException {
        if ( value == null ) {
            out.nullValue();
        } else {
            JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(value.get());
            elementAdapter.write(out, jsonElement);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        } else {
            // Read
            return null; // tmp
        }
    }

}
```

However I am not sure how to get the type of the generic for ObjectProperty in the TypeAdapter and I do not know how to get it from the TypeToken either (since I could pass it to the adapter from the factory).

---

**Summary of the question:**

1) How do I cast an implementation of `JsonSerializer/Deserializer` to TypeAdapter

**or**

2) How can I get the generic type for e.g. ObjectProperty from the TypeToken?

**or**

3) Do I need to do something completely different to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can't. `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` are the *old* converter way. New applications should use `TypeAdapter`, which has a superset of funcionality.

2) Assuming you mean JavaFX's [`ObjectProperty<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html) and you want to extract T's class.

You can access the `Type` inside `TypeToken` easily with `TypeToken#getType()`.

I will give the example with `List<String>` which is the same idea but easily testable.

```
TypeToken<List<String>> typeToken = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){};

System.out.println("typeToken.getRawType() = " + typeToken.getRawType());
Type type = typeToken.getType();
System.out.println("typeToken.getType() = " + type);
if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
  Type[] typeArguments = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments();
  System.out.println("typeArguments = " + Arrays.toString(typeArguments));
}
```

Output result:

```
typeToken.getRawType() = interface java.util.List
typeToken.getType() = java.util.List<java.lang.String>
typeArguments = [class java.lang.String]
```

3) I think you are nearly there. ;-) Ah, with the `TypeAdapter` you don't think in terms of `JsonObject` or `JsonElement` (DOM style) but you build the object or the JSON representation on the fly (stream style).

Also, in your question you say

> However I also need to use a TypeAdapterFactory because of nested
>   classes/object and direct serialisation, that do not work when
>   registering the serialisers directly to a GsonBuilder using
>   .registerTypeAdapter().

Maybe you need to use `GsonBuilder#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter()` and look for those nested classes. It will depend on your problem details.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the typeToken.getType is not an instance of ParameterizedType :/

Comment: What type it is? Can you debug it? Which information can you get from the TypeToken? I've also added another comment about `GsonBuilder#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter()`.

Comment: ```java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType```

Comment: Ok I needed to use: ```TypeToken<SimpleObjectProperty<CustomClass>> typeToken = new TypeToken<SimpleObjectProperty<CustomClass>>(){};``` instead of just ObjectProperty, since that is just an abstract class.